# load tableView based on newest timestamp

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I would like to sort a tableView based on the timestamp child value in Firebase. I would like the newest tableViewCell added to the tableView to be placed on top of the tableview every time the tableView loads (or reloads). Thanks for any help in advance!

// JSON from firebase

```
{
  "users" : {
    "CmtuebwVrmOG3n4uSsIK1b4FsSN2" : {
      "Places" : {
        "-KhDwZJvca9HedFluJ5O" : {
          "addedBy" : "CmtuebwVrmOG3n4uSsIK1b4FsSN2",
          "place" : "Edinburgh, UK",
          "timestamp" : 1.491678152020824E9
        },
        "-KhE7raDrM2RRs-N6FXg" : {
          "addedBy" : "CmtuebwVrmOG3n4uSsIK1b4FsSN2",
          "place" : "Hong Kong",
          "timestamp" : 1.49168137667081E9
        },
        "-KhFUaEjjhE3RBOw95fc" : {
          "addedBy" : "CmtuebwVrmOG3n4uSsIK1b4FsSN2",
          "place" : "Illinois, USA",
          "timestamp" : 1.491704112134812E9
        },
        "-KhzSIHrFHiUEBrzBKUH" : {
          "addedBy" : "CmtuebwVrmOG3n4uSsIK1b4FsSN2",
          "place" : "Ghana",
          "timestamp" : 1.492492039376661E9
        }
      },
```

// function to load tableview of places

```
    var placeList = [Place]()
    var placesDictionary = [String: Place]()

    func fetchPlaces() {

        let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(uid!).child("Places")
        ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {

                let place = Place()
                place.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
//                self.placeList.append(place)

                if let addedBy = place.addedBy {
                    self.placesDictionary[addedBy] = place
                    self.placeList.append(place)

                    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                    self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: self.placeList.count-1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
                    self.tableView.endUpdates()

                }

                //this will crash because of background thread, so lets call this on dispatch_async main thread
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })
            }

        }, withCancel: nil)

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the latest data record to be inserted into the 1st index of your array. Why don't you do something like this:

```
self.placeList.insert(place, at: 0)
```

rather than

```
self.placeList.append(place)
```

Btw, I don't think the following would be necessary:

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: self.placeList.count-1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes - the begin and end updates code seemed redundant to me as well.

Comment: No worries, please mark your question as answered if it solves your problem